# code to add to favourites fails silently

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `myList.php` which should list all products added to my favourites and compute the total price of products.

here is the code:

```
<?php     
    include 'navigation.php' 
?>

<div class='sectionContents'>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'removed') {
        echo "<div>" . $_GET['prod_name'] . " was removed from favourites.</div>";
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['fav'])) {
        $ids = "";
        foreach($_SESSION['fav'] as $prod_id) {
            $ids = $ids . $prod_id . ",";
        }

        // remove the last comma
        $ids = rtrim($ids, ',');

        include "db_connect.php";

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_price FROM tbl_product WHERE    prod_id IN ('$ids')") or die(mysql_error());

        $num = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($num > 0) {
            echo "<table border='0'>"; //start table

            // our table heading
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Price (MUR)</th>";
            echo "<th>Action</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            //also compute for total price
            $totalPrice = 0;

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                extract($row);

                $totalPrice += $prod_price;

                //creating new table row per record
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$prod_name}</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignRight'>{$prod_price}</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignCenter'>";
                echo "<a href='remove_favourite.php?prod_id=   {$prod_id}&prod_name={$prod_name}' class='customButton'>";
                echo "<img src='shopping-cart-in-php/images/remove-from-   cart.png' title='Remove from favourite' />";
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th class='textAlignCenter'>Total Price</th>";
            echo "<th class='textAlignRight'>{$totalPrice}</th>";
            echo "<th></th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "</table>";
            echo "<br /><div><a href='#' class='customButton'>Home</a></div>";

        } else {
            echo "<div>No products found in your favourites. :(</div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<div>No products in favourites yet.</div>";
    }
?>
```

I use the `add_to_fav.php` below to add the products to my favourites:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // get the product id
    $prod_id = $_GET['prod_id'];
    $prod_name = $_GET['prod_name'];

    /* 
     * check if the 'fav' session array was created
     * if it is NOT, create the 'fav' session array
     */

    if (!isset($_SESSION['fav'])) {
        $_SESSION['fav'] = array();
    }

    // check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
    if (in_array($prod_id, $_SESSION['fav'])) {
        // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to favourites
        header('Location: prod_list.php?action=exists&prod_id' . $prod_id . '&prod_name=' .    $prod_name);
    }

    // else, add the item to the array
    else {
        array_push($_SESSION['fav'], $prod_id);
        // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
        header('Location: prod_list.php?action=add&prod_id' . $prod_id . '&prod_name=' .  $prod_name);
    }

 ?>
```

I am having "No products found in your favourites. :(" when i try to view the favourites

I have a counter like thing which shows the number of products in my favourites as well and it stays to 0.

Have I erred somewhere? Which mistake should I correct?

Comment: Do you have a `session_start()` in the first file?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be happening.

1) You are not starting the session before loading the favorites:

```
<div class='sectionContents'>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='removed'){
    echo "<div>" . $_GET['prod_name'] . " was removed from favourites.</div>";
}

session_start()

if(isset($_SESSION['fav'])){
```

2) Your SQL query in fact is not finding any product ids. You might want to debug the SQL and run it in phpmyadmin or your mysql interface to see if it in fact does return any results.

```
include "db_connect.php";

$query = "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_price FROM tbl_product WHERE prod_id IN ('$ids')";
echo $query; // Print query for debugging
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

My guess is that this query is incorrect because of the single quotes around `$ids`

It should be:

```
$query = "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_price FROM tbl_product WHERE prod_id IN ($ids)";
```

Also this can be simplified from:

```
$ids = "";
foreach($_SESSION['fav'] as $prod_id){
    $ids = $ids . $prod_id . ",";
}

// remove the last comma
$ids = rtrim($ids, ',');
```

To:

```
$ids = implode(",", $_SESSION['fav']);
```

Comment: i am having this error message when i remove the single quotes from the $idsWarning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\buysmart_site\myList.php on line 41

Comment: Can you post what the `echo $query` output is? Also post what datatype the prod_id is in the database? Is it a varchar? int?

Comment: am having this - Resource id #6
No products found in your favourites. :( -  the datatype is int

Comment: you need to set the $query to the select statement like the code I have in the 2) suggestion, then you print the query, then you run the query. Don't try to echo the result of mysql_query. Since the datatype is int, then the sql query should work.